# react-select changing drop down indicator icon to font-awesome icon is not working

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-select

I am trying to change the icon used for the `react-select` multi select indictor to a font-awesome icon, but it is not working. Any idea why?

```
import React from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const Placeholder = props => {
  return <components.Placeholder {...props} />;
};

const CaretDownIcon = () => {
  return <i className="fas fa-caret-down" />;
};

const DropdownIndicator = props => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <CaretDownIcon />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{ Placeholder, DropdownIndicator }}
    placeholder={"Choose"}
    styles={{
      placeholder: base => ({
        ...base,
        fontSize: "1em",
        color: colourOptions[2].color,
        fontWeight: 400
      })
    }}
    options={colourOptions}
  />
);
```

The item tag is shown in the DOM, but I do not see the icon.

[image: DOM]

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? And do you see `i` tag is appearing in the DOM?

Comment: No console errors, and yes, I do see the item tag in the DOM. Posting image above.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I recommend you to check the documentation of [Font Awesome for React](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react).

To achieve the desired result I end up with the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select, { type DropdownIndicatorProps, components } from 'react-select'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCaretDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

library.add(faCaretDown);


const CaretDownIcon = () => {
  return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />;
};

// added type if using typescript
const DropdownIndicator: React.FC<DropdownIndicatorProps> = props => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <CaretDownIcon />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        components={{ Placeholder, DropdownIndicator }}
        placeholder={"Choose"}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y320oyq5n) a live example of what you want.

Comment: Oh, nice, this is using svg. So weird, today I loaded my app and the icon has changed to the font-awesome icon, somehow, but I like the idea of using the svg instead. Is this the recommended practice when using React?

Comment: @thehme at least it's the way font awesome is recommending it, but I agree svg is a nice approach :)

Comment: This really help.

Comment: @Laura, could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70196104/set-state-inside-a-component-in-reactjs

Comment: Yeah, we should use @fortawesome/react-fontawesome for react fontawesome