# How to make react-select as textarea

Tags: reactjs, css, react-select

Hello there I am using react-select while using, it is by default dropdown list. Can someone guide me how can i customize it.I want react-select as textarea.

any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Here is my image what actually I am looking for.

How can I make it as textarea?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by textarea? You can already write in in by default, right?

Comment: what do you mean by "I want react-select as textarea"? you want the selected options to appear in a text area? from where you want to select items?  what have you done, how does it look now? how do you want it to look like? Your question is so vague

Comment: react-select by default functionality is drop down. I want it customize like i have showed in image.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi right i want selected  options in textarea

Comment: @Nammu Do you mean [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/7mwv5rzwvx)?

Comment: @Tholle right but its showing in drop down list. I want customize it. Like my image that is a text box

Comment: @Nammu But you can write in the input, and it gives you a dropdown with search results. You don't want any dropdown functionality at all?

Comment: @Tholle that example only I have implemented right now but I want customize that dropdown list to textarea.

Comment: @Tholle I think what he wants is the area that shows selected options be separated from the dropdown list. like dropdown in sidemenu and the selected option is header? like these job searching sites

Comment: @Tholle no i want functionality same i dont want to change any functionality I just want to customize it like my image.

Comment: It's impossible to understand what you mean by "as my image". Select 2 or more options in the codesandbox link I sent you above, and you will see that it look like your image. If that's not it, you have to be more specific.

Comment: @Tholle sorry for taking your time. Can you just tell me how can I remove that dropdown icon which is showing in example and i want increase the width and hight of that input.

Comment: It seems that the element is input. I also need textarea, so that I can create values that are multiline by pressing enter. The idea is the same as Input-component in Material-UI with multiline attribute. My need is to create textarea that allows searching through ajax and also entering custom values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that you just want to remove the dropdown icon. You can take example on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586184/react-select-changing-drop-down-indicator-icon-to-font-awesome-icon-is-not-worki/54598963#54598963) and edit the code to remove it like this.

```
const DropdownIndicator = () => null;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
        styles={{
          indicatorSeparator: base => ({
            ...base,
            display: 'none'
          })
        }}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jj1l2prx9y).

Comment: thanks for reply, and thanks for giving your valuable time here.Your answer is acceptable.can we fix the height of select? as per image! suppose I am adding more content into it so it should show scrollbar after some extends.

Comment: @Nammu Have you tried the example ? Actually, when the label exceed the width of the label (by default 100% of the parent) it adds ellipsis and no scrollbar.

Comment: Yes I have tried with your answer its working, the only thing currently I am looking is to fix the height of select, I tried it but the size of content height is also increasing. Is there any way to put content on top and fix the height of select after some level?

Comment: @Nammu you could create a different question with you code update ? I'm not sure to get what you're trying to achieve and where you are in our progress.