# Set state inside a component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component in my react js application:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select, { components, DropdownIndicatorProps } from "react-select";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  console.log(state);
  const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
    const { menuIsOpen } = props.selectProps;
    setState(menuIsOpen);
    return (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>12</components.DropdownIndicator>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
      defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
      isMulti
      options={colourOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default Component;
```

In the DropDownIndicator component i set the state:

```js
const {
  menuIsOpen
} = props.selectProps;
setState(menuIsOpen);
```

Setting the state in that place i get the next warning: `Warning: Cannot update a component (Component) while rendering a different component (DropdownIndicator). To locate the bad setState() call inside DropdownIndicator` . 
 Question: How can i fix this warning and to make it disappear? 
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-97sx0?file=/example.tsx:0-724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `setState` inside `useEffect`

```
const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
    const { menuIsOpen } = props.selectProps;

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(menuIsOpen);
      });

    return (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>12</components.DropdownIndicator>
    );
  };
```

*What does **useEffect** do? By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render.* [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  about useEffect

Incase if your `setState` is depend of `menuIsOpen`. Pass to `useEffect` as dependency.

```
 const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
    const { menuIsOpen } = props.selectProps;

      useEffect(() => {
        setState(menuIsOpen);
      },[menuIsOpen]);

    return (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>12</components.DropdownIndicator>
    );
  };
```

Complete solution on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-yplpf)

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the `useState` with default value as `false`

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(false);
```

looks like when you are doing `setState(menuIsOpen);` for the first time, its value is `undefined` and `DropdownIndicator` is not yet finished with first rendering,

[Hypothesis] There must be some code with React.Component as per the stack trace, based on undefined/null check. But when given initialState, the error is not occurring.